# WindowsCE 5.0 safe tcp ports

Tags: c#, tcp, windows-ce, port

What ports are safe to use for custom applications under WindowsCE?
For example if I use something around 3000 (3000, 3002 tested) it works. But if I use 4000, 11000 (tested), it does not work: it appears to be successfull in the server but nobody can connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "safe"?  Just "open and usable"?  There aren't any ports that are inherently blocked, though some services that you might incluse in the OS image could well use a port (e.g. HTTPD uses port 80). 4000 and 11000 are not used by any CE service, so they will be open, though your network itself could be filtering them at a router.

Comment: By safe I mean, not used by system applications.

Comment: Since CE is modular, there isn't any list.  The list of ports in use depends on what components were selected when the OS was generated.